# Filtering Visual Odometry and IMU/GPS data

Tags: navigation, gps, viso2-ros, robot-pose-ekf, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

during the past months I have been working on gettings results from a stereo-cam system
using ROS-package viso2_ros in a moving vehicle. So far so good, the egomotion estimation from visual
odometry really works well as can be seen here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lsqHfEHf7g4K1UC0KOJIlh22V57SYQLA5EkSOBJr0fg/edit

I now have wheel_odometry, visual_odometry, IMU and GPS-data in ASCII-files ready to be processed and filtered (also have a reference trajectory giving the "true" position). Here is the data:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1b1mlDmiL4wQm9DdVAzX0lWYmc/edit?usp=sharing

I can filter all the data with the package "robot_pose_ekf".
The disadvantage is that the package uses the orientation from the IMU rather than
angular rates and acceleration. This orientation is drifting and not accurate.

I was wondering if you could give me tips how to build a filter which fuses all
the described data. If possible the design of the filter should not be that complicated
since I donot have that much knowledge about EKFs. Also any good literature recommendation is appreciated.

Hector

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192763/filtering-visual-odometry-and-imu/gps-data/) by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karry3775](https://answers.ros.org/users/53272/karry3775/) on 2020-04-06**:
Hi I am also using viso2_ros inside gazebo to get stereo visual odometry. I am facing issues with translation estimates. When my robot is standstill, even then there is some forward motion estimate given by the package. Did you ever face these issues ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization)? It accepts angular velocities, though linear acceleration is not (yet) supported.

However, I'm surprised that you're getting drift from robot_pose_ekf. Have you tried plotting the raw sensor data?

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on 2014-09-16**:
Yes I did. Actually that is what my supervisor told me, e.g. if an xsens is in rest, the orientation [computed by xsens] will drift over time. I also have some experience with that. My former colleague has put up a video of his error state filter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymuhJ6pt52o.